# extract text plugin not working

Tags: webpack, text-extraction

There is no error thrown but the plugin is just not working.
There should be a new css file compiled from both .scss and .css files

Here is my config file.

```
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].js',
    },
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                ....
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader',
                }),
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader|sass-loader',
                }),
            },

        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('src/styles.css'),
    ],

};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using webpack 4 and the latest beta for the plugin

Comment: `css-loader|sass-loader` should be an array with `'css-loader,' 'sass-loader'`, and why do you write the output to `src/style.css`? But it is working fine